# How to refer to component's controller outside the HTML element (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs

I'm at step3 at https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03. There it is asked to show the number of phones, like in step 2, but now making use of the component-construction.

I tried adding, after the line

```html
<phone-list></phone-list>
```

```html
<p>Total number of phones: {{$ctrl.phones.length}}</p>
```

and

```html
<p>Total number of phones: {{phoneList.phones.length}}</p>
```

and others but I can't figure out how it is meant to be done here in the tutorial? None of these solutions show the number of phones.

Comment: Where is your component?

Comment: In phone-list.component.js, defined as angular.module('phonecatApp').
component('phoneList', .... the phone-list is shown fine in the <phone-list> element.

Comment: A good question is half of the answer. It shouldn't be referred outside. That's the idea of component.

Comment: The tutorial says: *Now add another binding to the phoneList component's template*, and gives the code right after. The HTML must be added in the phone-list component's template. Not in the  template using <phone-list>

Comment: Ah that makes sense. It wasn't clear to me that the instruction under the second bullet was meant as an instruction on how to perfom the instruction under the first bullet. Thanks.